# Dynamic link on ios open black page

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

When we try to open a dynamic link on an iPhone (iOS 10) without our app, the browser is opened on a blank page with a button in the middle instead of the store....why?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from google

> This behavior on iOS where your dynamic links show intermediate Screen is an intended behavior. This is meant to address some issues with Dynamic Links on iOS when clicking on the link from within an app. For example, for certain apps clicking on the link would not take the user to the App Store when the app wasn't installed, or the link parameters would not get passed when the app was installed so the user wasn't taken to the correct in-app content.

Comment: I have a similar but when I click on the open link in the intermediate screen it takes me to the App Store even if I have the app installed and then it doesn't pass parameters to the app by opening it through the App Store. If I open the link through chrome it opens the app and doesn't go through the intermediate screen.

Comment: Have you created the dynamic link in the right way (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener)?

Comment: You might also get this page after you clicked the goo.gl link in the status bar of your app (after opening it via universal link). You may "fix" this by long pressing on the button on the page and choose "open in <yourApp>". this way the system will store your preference to open universal links for the specified URL in your app and not the associated website.

Comment: There is a new 'efr' parameter you can add to your dynamic link (https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually):
'efr' parameter allows you to 'Skip the app preview page when the Dynamic Link is opened on iOS, and instead redirect to the app or App Store. The app preview page (enabled by default) can more reliably send users to the most appropriate destination when they open Dynamic Links in apps; however, if you expect a Dynamic Link to be opened only in apps that can open Dynamic Links reliably without this page, you can disable it with this parameter.'

Comment: If I set forcedRedirectEnabled = true (efr=1) it always redirect to the app store even if the app is installed. It works fine if I set it to 0. Anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Firebase Console]

Firebase Dynamic Links provides default dynamic links as follows:

**Long Dynamic Link:**
https://preview.page.link/?link=https://example.com//&apn=com.example.package&isi=123456789&ibi=com.example.package

**Short Dynamic Link:**
https://preview.page.link/linkpreview

Above both links will redirect you to App Preview Page on iOS devices.

[image]

You can **bypass or skip the App Preview Page** by specifying the dynamic link parameter **efr=1**.

And now your Dynamic Link URL will look like

https://preview.page.link/?link=https://example.com/&apn=com.example.package&isi=123456789&ibi=com.example.package&efr=1

Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews#app_preview_pages