# Change language on "open link" page

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

When I open dynamic links on iOS, the browser is opened on a blank page that says "Open link in app?". As I understand it, this is an [intended behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369653/dynamic-link-on-ios-open-black-page).

How can I change the language on this page?
(Or alternatively: How can I supress that page?)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly new Dynamic Links feature, so it appears the Firebase team has not (yet) built any options for controlling or customizing the message. You'd could probably build this yourself as the fallback URL, but that still wouldn't allow you to suppress the message.

Alternatively, at [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team), the equivalent functionality is called [Deepviews](https://branch.io/features/#deepviews). Deepviews do allow customization and localization, and can be turned off (at risk of sometimes not giving deep linking behavior)